# How to determine when file copying is ended?

Tags: c#, copy, filesystems, .net

How to determine when file copying is ended
i'm using c#

edit: we copying files through network from one pc to another one.
my task is to watch directory and do some actions after files are copied to it.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Why do you think the file is not fully copied?

Comment: Yeah. File copy is a blocking operation, or?

Comment: Isn't System.IO.File.Copy() blocking until completion?

Comment: I think `File.IO.Copy` is synchronous ...

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `File.Copy()` then this operation is finished *after* file is actually copied.

Answer (score 3):

Try looking into [FileSystemWatcher's Created event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created%28VS.71%29.aspx).

> Some common occurrences, such as
>   copying or moving a file or directory,
>   do not correspond directly to an
>   event, but these occurrences do cause
>   events to be raised. When you copy a
>   file or directory, `the system raises a
>   Created event` in the directory to
>   which the file was copied

Comment: The event will be raised as soon as the file is created. It does not mean that data in file in completely written.

Answer (score 2):

Periodically check for size.
Anyway, I recommend you to use `CopyFileEx`, that has a progress feature (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: i thought about this idea before. when i should stop checking.

Comment: when the size is equal to the size of the original file.

Comment: i should tell you guys before that i'm copying file from one pc to another through network. i'm copying file not from code.

Comment: even so, you could get the size before starting to copy.

Comment: how i can get it? filesystem watcher doesn't provide this information

Comment: it should not count whether the file is on your disk or on some other computer in your network - it's only the address that differs.

Answer (score 1):

I have came across something similar recently. 
I would use File's open write attribute on the file to see if you can write to the file:
e.g. 
FileStream fs = f.OpenWrite();

if the above statement works then file is not in use i.e. done copying.

Comment: well, can i somehow manipulate with copying file dialog on pc (to determine when it is closed)?
i.e. not using watcher on target dir

Comment: I dont know if this is a best thing to do. To start with you will need to identify process . The file copying process comes under "windows explorer" (if you use task manager). Unless someone knows how to get the correct process easily.

One other way to do is to try to rename the destination directory (e.g. something like Directory.Move()) if you can do this then directory is not in use and all files have been copied to the directory.

thx